# Oracle DB Query Custom Order by

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-order-by, sql-like

I'm looking for a way to accomplish something kind of like fuzzy search with Oracle.  If this has already been answered, I'll gladly accept a link, but I'm so new to Oracle that I'm not even sure how to quickly search for what I want.

Given the following query:

```
SELECT VEND_CUST_CD, LGL_NM, ALIAS_NM
FROM {{DB_NAME}}.{{DB_TABLE}}
WHERE ({{condition_1}}) AND ({{condition_2}}) AND (upper(LGL_NM) LIKE upper('%{{term}}%')
ORDER BY LGL_NM
```

What I'd like to get in my response is a particular order.  Let's imagine `term`=`ze` for the purposes of this.

I'd like to get results ordered like so:

- **Ze**alot Johnson
- **Ze**bra Eaters
- **Ze**ro Gravity
- Ama**ze**d John
- Bedaz**ze**l
- La**ze**r Sex
- Za**ze**w

So that what I'm getting back first is words that start with `term` followed by an alphabetical list of words that contain `term` within them.

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you can order the results like so:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LGL_NM LIKE '{{term}}%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, LGL_NM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all like this:

```
select * from (
SELECT VEND_CUST_CD, LGL_NM, ALIAS_NM
FROM {{DB_NAME}}.{{DB_TABLE}}
WHERE ({{condition_1}}) AND ({{condition_2}}) AND (upper(LGL_NM) LIKE upper('{{term}}%')

union all

SELECT VEND_CUST_CD, LGL_NM, ALIAS_NM
FROM {{DB_NAME}}.{{DB_TABLE}}
WHERE ({{condition_1}}) AND ({{condition_2}}) AND (upper(LGL_NM) LIKE upper('{{%term%}}') AND (upper(LGL_NM) not LIKE upper('{{term%}}')

) order by ...
```

or like @Salman A 's way

Comment: @lustin . . . SQL results sets are unordered, unless there is an explicit `order by` clause.  The `union all` is not sufficient to *guarantee* that the results are in a particular order.  (This is something that usually works in practice, but is not guaranteed.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're probably right, I didn t test it... but I will

Comment: @GordonLinoff please correct me if I'm wrong: union all can really do some order. if we have for e.g.: select 2 from dual union select 1 from dual .. right?